# Setting up django with uwsgi and nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to serve django 1.5 app with uwsgi and nginx. Following is my ini file

```
[uwsgi]
# variables
projectname = mysite
projectdomain = mysite.in
base = /home/shwetanka/projects/me/mysite

# config
plugins = python
master = true
protocol = uwsgi
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(base)/%(projectname).settings
#pythonpath = %(base)/src/%(projectname)
module = %(base)/mysite/wsgi.py
socket = 127.0.0.1:8889
logto = %(base)/logs/uwsgi.log
#below line runs it as a daemon in background
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/mysite.log
```

I'm getting this error in logs -

```
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - *** Starting uWSGI 1.2.3-debian (64bit) on [Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013] ***
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 07 November 2012 03:49:52
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - detected number of CPU cores: 4
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - current working directory: /
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - uwsgi socket 0 inherited UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/mysite/socket fd 3
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - uwsgi socket 1 inherited INET address 127.0.0.1:8889 fd 5
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - Python version: 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:30:41)  [GCC 4.7.3]
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0xd36dc0
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 6093)
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 6245, cores: 1)
Sat Aug 31 14:05:35 2013 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 6246, cores: 1)
```

How do I get it working?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.

The `--module` directive expect a module, not a file. You should use `--wsgi-file` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the django module with: `--module mysite.wsgi:application`

And don't forget to add: `--env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings`

For instance, a working command line is (provided your current directory is your project home):

```
uwsgi --socket mysite/zohosel.sock  --module mysite.wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings --home=/path/to/your/venv --chmod-socket=666
```

Some extra information and arguments can be found on [the django docs website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/).
And by the way, this [tutorial on readthedocs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` correctly,

then run `uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi` on the same directory, `mysite` is your django project's name.

ref: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: uwsgi: unrecognized option '--module' . version:2.0.18