# uWsgi server not running correctly due to interpreter mode

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

This is my first rodeo with `uWsgi` - but after hours of trying to configure it, it hasn't been the smoothest process.

I'm running `uWsgi` with `Nginx` (`nginx` is running fine).

I'm trying to load `uwsgi` with:
1) `uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:5000 --chdir /path/to/my/django/application --wsgi-file django/application/wsgi.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2`

or

2)    `uwsgi --ini runserver.ini`

The result: neither end up properly deploying the application.

When I run the second command attempt I get output like:

```
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /my/django/application/directory
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:5000 fd 3
Python version: 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Feb 27 2014, 19:56:00)  [GCC 4.4.3]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x86ac688
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 357000 bytes (348 KB) for 8 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
failed to open python file hook_project/wsgi.py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 7477)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 7478, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 7479, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 7480, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 7481, cores: 2)
```

**nginx config**

```
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8003;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    access_log /var/www/nginx_log/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/nginx_log/error.log;
    charset     utf-8;

    location /static {
        # the Django project's static files
        alias /path/to/django/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # or the uwsgi_params you installed manually
    }
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste
}
```

Can anyone suggest why my app is not loading at all and uwsgi is failing on loading the django app?

Comment: Please add your nginx configuration .

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546299/setting-up-django-with-uwsgi-and-nginx

Comment: And also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163640/django-virtualenv-nginx-uwsgi-import-module-wsgi-error I think your problem relates to path so try changing wsgi.py and add correct path.

Comment: Your uWsgi configuration is fine. I was facing the same issue and i resolved it by reverting my branch to previous commit and the error was because of some un-tracked files